# Nginx 499 Error after Pod on openshift redeployed

Tags: docker, nginx, deployment, openshift

I have an openshift cluster where all of the services are deployed to. All services are not accessible outside of the cluster except for my frontend service which is a nginx docker container. 
This nginx docker container is redirecting api equests to other services within the cluster. So far everything works as expected.

The problem is that if one of the service is removed and redeployed, nginx can't redirect to this service anymore and returns a 499 client closed request error.

I assume that the reason lies because the pod name changed after a redeploy and that's why it can't find the service but I'm not sure. If my assumption is right, how can I fix this or lies my problem somewhere else?

My Nginx configuration:

```html
worker_processes  1;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 3072;
}

http {
    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    # configure caching according to file-type
    map $sent_http_content_type $expires {
        default                    off;
        text/html                  epoch; # means no cache, as it is not a static page
        text/css                   1d;
        application/javascript     1d;
        application/woff2          1d;

        # cache images for a day
        ~image/                    1d;
    }

    server {

        listen 8080;
        expires $expires;

        gzip              on;
        gzip_http_version 1.1;
        gzip_disable      "MSIE [1-6]\.";
        gzip_min_length   256;
        gzip_vary         on;
        gzip_proxied      expired no-cache no-store private auth;
        gzip_types        text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
        gzip_comp_level   9;

        root /usr/share/nginx/html;

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
        }

        location /api/ {
            proxy_pass http://kerberos/;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How is your Nginx configured?

Comment: I updated my question with my nginx configuration.

Comment: How does the nginx know about the backend services. I only see a proxy_pass for the kerberos service. Because it is using the service name, there should be no issue with the pods being restarted, new traffic will still make it. BTW, if only want to forward based on sub URL, why not use path in a route to direct just that traffic to a service. Would mean you have to be using custom domain name though.

Comment: Nginx knows only about kerberos. Based on the url, e.x. http://kerberos/abc-service, kerberos is redirecting to proper service. I'm sorry about the confusion. The main problem is when kerberos is redeployed and (I assume) has a different pod name, which can't be resolved by nginx afterwards. But as mentioned before, I'm not sure about this assumption.

Comment: Because you use ``http://kerberos/``, restarting of pods and their names changes is not an issue. This is because you are actually contacting the IP of the service called 'kerberos', this doesn't change. OpenShift automatically reconfigures internal routing for pods when they come and go so the IP of the service always ends up at a currently active pod.

Comment: Yes you're totally right about this. This is what I also thought at first. However whenever I redeploy kerberos, Nginx ends up with 499 response. I can't explain this behaviour neither.

Comment: But a 499 is indicative of client closing connection and not the connection to the backend. Unless the clients are keeping keep alive connections right through to the backend and the restart is causing an issue with that. As a test, reduce the keep alive timeout or even turn it off and see what happens.

Comment: I used  `keepalive_timeout 0;` but unfortunately I still experience the same issue.

Comment: Okej I see now that that the Ip address of the services changes when I redeploy, and nginx tries to connect to the old ip address. I'm now trying to find a solution so nginx resolves the domain on each request somehow.